# Can a statically-typed language support heterogeneous lists?

Tags: list, typing, dynamic-typing, static-typing

In Python, I can easily create a list containing values of various types, e.g.:

```
[0, 1.0, '2', MyClass(3)]
```

However, in the statically-typed languages I am familiar with, lists can only contain values of a single type. For example, C++'s `std::vector<T>` can only hold values of type `T`. C#'s `List<T>` is similar.

Is it possible for a statically-typed language to support heterogeneous lists? If so, which languages have such support?

Comment: You could have a list of `boost::any` types.  `any` has been accepted into standard for c++17 but I'm not sure if an implementation is available. It uses a technique called type erasure, to allow the elements to store anything. The downside to this as far as I know is that the items must conform to a predefined interface or must be cast before they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Java you *could* do this by using type `Object`, but to me it stinks like a Java anti-pattern and you probably *should* not do it :P

```
package teststackoverflowquestion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestStackOverflowQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(10);
        list.add(10.50);
        list.add("blahblah");
        list.add(new MyClass(3));

        list.stream().forEach(o -> System.out.println(o.getClass() + "  : " + o));
        System.out.println("-------------");
        list.stream().filter(o -> o.getClass().equals(Integer.class))
                .forEach(o -> System.out.println((int) o + 4));
    }
}

class MyClass {
    int someField;
    public MyClass(int someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(someField);
    }
}
```

Output:

> class java.lang.Integer  : 10
>   class java.lang.Double  : 10.5
>   class java.lang.String  : blahblah
>   class teststackoverflowquestion.MyClass  : 3
>   -------------
>   14

Comment: Can you directly query the types in this list, though?   In C++ the types on a std::tuple are explicit.

Comment: I'm not sure actually what you can or can't do with it, I've never used it before and I'm trying things with it for the first time now.  Tbh it stinks like a Java anti-pattern.  Since it's basically just using polymorphism, I don't think the exact type needs to be known at compile time.  It uses `Object` as type,  so I assume all you can do with it is call methods defined in `Object`, and that's [not much](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).  But you *can* make a list like that :P

Answer (score 0):

c++ has std::tuple, though the types have to be known at compile time.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

Also, you can have a pointer/reference to any descendent of a parent type, as well.

list{fordptr, chevyptr};